# display a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating an API and I want to show a code example in javascript that you can use to invoke the API.

I write a test function in javascript.  I would like to be able to execute AND display the code for the javascript function(s) but I would rather only have one copy of the code to make maintenance easier.

Example, I have the following code:

```
function doauth_test(apikey,username,userpass)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/v1.2/user.php/doauth/" + username + "/" + userpass + "?apikey=" + apikey,
        type: "GET",
        success: function(data,textStatus,xhr) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            var authkey = obj.authkey; //store this somewhere for subsequent use
            var user_id = obj.user_id; //store this somewhere for subsequent use
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert("ERROR!  Status code:  " + xhr.status + " Response Text: " + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

I want this code to be something I can EXECUTE and I want it to display the code in a DIV in my documentation example.  But I do not want to (ideally) have two copies of this code.

Comment: Just use `doauth_test.toString()`.

Comment: Possible duplicated? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16743385/run-and-display-code-as-text-without-repeating/16743461#16743461

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can call `toString()` on a function to get its source code.

Alternatively, you can use the DOM to get the text of the `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

Just use toString method for your function and it will return your function definition as a string.

```
alert(doauth_test.toString());
```

Hope it helps!